# Problems using local DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I am trying to set up openbalena on a virtual machine, and it requires DNS records in order to be discoverable. I have set up bind9 like so:

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.local";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168.0";
};
```

`/etc/bind/zones/db.local`

```
@       IN      SOA     local. admin.local. (
                              5         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS     openbalena.local.

openbalena.local.          IN   A      192.168.0.166
api.openbalena.local.      IN   CNAME  openbalena.local.
registry.openbalena.local. IN   CNAME  openbalena.local.
vpn.openbalena.local.      IN   CNAME  openbalena.local.
s3.openbalena.local.       IN   CNAME  openbalena.local.
```

There is also a corresponding reverse lookup zone. Since the DNS server is running on the same server as openbalena, the addresses are the same.

I am able to access the records like so:

```
$ nslookup openbalena.local 192.168.0.166
Server:     192.168.0.166
Address:    192.168.0.166#53

Name:   openbalena.local
Address: 192.168.0.166
```

However, if I omit the DNS address I get this error

```
$ nslookup openbalena.local
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find openbalena.local: SERVFAIL
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

And `systemd-resolve --status` gives me this information (abridged):

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.166
                      192.168.0.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
[...]

Link 3 (wlp1s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.166
                      192.168.0.1

[...]
```

The local DNS server seems to be at the top of the list, so I'm not sure why this is not working. Of course I could add the relevant names to `/etc/hosts`, but I need this to work for another device on the network where that's not an option. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like nslookup is using your gateway as a DNS resolver, and since it cannot resolve the `openbalena.local` domain, you get the `SERVFAIL` error. You should instead add forwards to the options section of `named.conf` and remove `192.168.0.1` from DNS servers list for desired effect.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have configured your pc to use your new DNS as your DNS? It's easily forgotten.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard Do you know why it's using the gateway even though the 166 server is listed first? The DNS is running on a VM, not a permanent server so I would strongly prefer it not being the only DNS option, especially since we are multiple people using this network for home office right now

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom I've added the DNS address to the DHCP server. I included my `/etc/resolv.conf` and related information, and the DNS address indeed seems to be correct

Comment: Bind is listening on an IP address other than 127.0.0.1? Port 53 is open on the name server box? You didn't mention firewall. Is your address hard coded or issued by DHCP?

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom I'm using DHCP. I don't see how it could be a firewall issue since the query completes successfully if I specify the DNS address (as shown in the first `nslookup` command in the question)

Comment: set the ip to 192.x.x.x and retry instead of 127

Comment: @djdomi which IP are you suggesting that I change?

Comment: @Vegaard: It is a bit "random". On my network i have 2 DNS servers (a primary and a slave - running on two different Raspberry Pies). Sometimes sometimes the primary is responding and sometimes it is the secondary that responds. It is a bit back and forth who respond, so i guess some `Round Robin` algorithm is involved.

Comment: @vangard change the localhost ip in resolv. conf to your 192 dns ip